# Joint Prior Distribution for $Uniform(a,b)$ (a,b unknown)

Tags: bayesian, mathematical-statistics, inference, conditional-probability

I have some problems in figuring out how to address the following problem and some help would be welcomed.

> **Exercise**
>
> Consider a Continuous Uniform Distribution over the $
> (a,b)$ interval where $a< b$ are both unknown parameters.
>
> a) Find a joint prior distribution for the vector of parameters $(a,b)$ such that it is conjugate family for the $Uniform(a,b)$ distribution.
>
> b) Based on a) find the prior marginal distribution for each parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this is an exercise, I will not solve the whole thing for you, but I will get you started by showing how you would go about finding the conjugate prior kernel.  This will give you a basis to then solve the two problems in your question.  This first step is essentially just a matter of writing down the likelihood function for your problem, and then formulating a conjugate prior kernel that is a function of the same mathematical form.

---

**Determining the conjugate prior kernel:** Given observed data $x_1,x_2,...,x_n \sim \text{IID U}(a, b)$ the likelihood function for a fixed data vector $\mathbf{x}$ is:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
L_\mathbf{x}(a,b) 
&= \prod_{i=1}^n \text{U}(x_i|a,b) \\[6pt]
&= \prod_{i=1}^n \frac{\mathbb{I}(a \leqslant x_i \leqslant b)}{b-a} \\[6pt]
&= \frac{1}{(b-a)^n} \prod_{i=1}^n \mathbb{I}(a \leqslant x_i \leqslant b) \\[6pt]
&= \frac{1}{(b-a)^n} \cdot \mathbb{I}(a \leqslant x_{(1)}) \cdot \mathbb{I}(b \geqslant x_{(n)}). \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

The conjugate prior should be of the same form as this function, in order to yield a posterior density that has the same form.  I would therefore posit the **conjugate prior kernel**:

$$\pi(a,b|\alpha,\beta,\lambda) \propto \frac{1}{(b-a)^{\lambda+1}} \cdot \mathbb{I}(a \leqslant \alpha) \cdot \mathbb{I}(b \geqslant \beta), \quad \quad \quad \quad$$

where $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\lambda$ are [hyperparameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperparameter).  It is trivial to establish the **posterior density**:

$$\pi(a,b|\mathbf{x},\alpha,\beta,\lambda) 
= \pi(a,b|\min(\alpha,x_{(1)}), \max(\beta,x_{(n)}), \lambda+n).$$

Now, with a bit of calculus we can determine that the prior density kernel leads to the proper prior distribution over the range $-\infty < \alpha < \beta < \infty$ and $\lambda > 1$.  In the case $0 < \lambda \leqslant 1$ we have an improper prior but a proper posterior (since $n \geqslant 1$), so we can generalise the conjugate prior to allow a hyperparameter in this range if we want.  This prior distribution is essentially a bivariate extension of the [Pareto distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution).

---

> a) Find a joint prior distribution for the vector of parameters $(a,b)$ such that it is conjugate family for the $\text{U}(a,b)$ distribution.

The above section shows you how to get the kernel of the conjugate prior distribution.  To find the corresponding density function you only need to find the normalising constant, which is a simple calculus problem.  This will also tell you the allowable range of the hyperparameters that give you either a proper prior and/or a proper posterior.

> b) Based on a) find the prior marginal distribution for each parameter.

Once you have successfully derived the joint prior density, this should be a straight-forward calculus problem.  To obtain the marginal densities of each parameter you simply integrate over the range of the other parameter.

Comment: This is something like an extension of the usual Pareto$(\alpha,\lambda)$ distribution with the addition of the $\beta$ parameter to "model" the second parameter of the Uniform Distribution, right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  Here we impose upper and lower bounds on the parameters to act as conjugate terms to the upper and lower bounds in the likelihood function.

Comment: Okay. I got it. Thanks a lot for this. So the addition of the 1 to the exponent on the recent edition is only meant to fit the usual parametrization of the Pareto Distribution but we could still proceed without that 1 addition as long as the normalising constat is correctly computed, right?

Comment: Later or tomorrow I will update the complete exercise (this is only a part of it) and the complete solution as an edition of the current post to make sure it's public. Thanks again.

Comment: That's right - it is really just a matter of deciding what range you wan the hyperparameter $\lambda$ to have.  I have set the prior density to be siilar to the Pareto.